# Configure Authentication Filters and Filter Chains via REST for GeoServer

Tags: rest, geoserver

Is there any possibility to configure authentication filters and filter chains in the security section of GeoServer via REST?

I could not find anything in the [documentation](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/rest/).